# Burned Outlet and burned and lo frayed wires is this safe to put a new outlet

Tags: electrical, walls, insulation, safety, house

[image]

Me and my dad are fixing a burnt outlet and when we opened it we found out that the wires were frayed and burned is it safe to rewire these to the new outlet.

So apparently the tenant said that he turned on a light and said that there was a burn smell and he saw the outlet burned. This is what I saw when I opened it up I thought it would Be as simple as putting the old wires back to the new outlet but I’m not too sure what to do now

Comment: Pictures please.  Frayed is usually seen on very old wires and the insulation might not liked to be touched/handled, so it makes repairs more difficult.

Comment: Yeah, we’re going to need a lot more information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and use the "Sun & Mountains" button to add some pics.

Comment: I thought I added a pic idk what happened don’t roast me 

Comment: You may not legally do electrical work on a rental if you're not a licensed electrician. You'll need to hire a licensed electrician to cut the damaged wire out and splice in a repair (possibly at an upstream location).

Answer (score 3):

STOP!

You are working on a rental property. You are absolutely NOT allowed to work on this. Only a certified electrician can work on a rental property, whether you're a tenant or owner.

Comment: You'll wonder why owners can work on their own property, because the consequences (death, property loss) are theirs to bear. A rental property owner cannot do this, because it leads to slumlord situations, so only certified electricians can work on rental properties.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for adding a photo.

I'm seeing damage to the wire insulation where I think you were describing burned wires.

The copper looks good, but that's the only good news.  The lengths of the wires where the insulation is damaged is now unusable for this circuit.

I can't tell from the photo if you have enough usable wire insulation near the back to be able to safely splice some new wires inside this box.

Also, the remaining insulation is so dirty that I can't identify the wires.  My educated guess is that you had 2 white and 2 black wires somewhere in there.  That means you should also have 2 ground wires and an attachment point for them on the box, but I can't see that from the photo.

The only thing I can say for sure is that you need to remove some of the length of those wires just in the process of cleaning up this box.  After that, you will still need to determine the extent of the damage to what remains.  That includes evaluating any possible damage that could have extended beyond the inside of the box.

Comment: The OP may not actually do anything electrical in a rental except call a licensed electrician.